# Selecting records from subquery found set (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query on 2 tables (part, price).  The simplified version of this query is:

```
SELECT price.* 
FROM price 
INNER JOIN parts ON (price.code = part.code ) 
WHERE price.type = '01' 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

That returns several records:

```
 code        | type     | date                | price      |  file
-------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------
 00065064705 | 01       | 2008-01-07 00:00:00 |  16.400000 | 28SEP2011.zip
 00065064705 | 01       | 2007-02-05 00:00:00 |  15.200000 | 20JUL2011.zip
 54868278900 | 01       | 2006-02-24 00:00:00 |  16.642000 | 28SEP2011.zip
```

As you can see, there is code `00065064705` listed twice.  I just need the maxdate record (2008-01-07) along with the code, type, date and price for each unique code.  So basically the top record for each unique code.  This postgres so I can't use SELECT TOP or something like that.

I think I should be using this as subquery inside of a main query but I'm not sure how.  something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM price 
JOIN (insert my original query here) AS price2 ON price.code = price2.code
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to do that.

```
select *
  from (SELECT price.*,
               row_number() over (partition by price.code order by price.date desc) as rn
          FROM price
         INNER JOIN parts ON (price.code = part.code ) 
         WHERE price.type='01') x
 where rn = 1
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

(*) Note: I may have prefixed some of the columns incorrectly, as I'm not sure which column is in which table.  I'm sure you can fix that.

Comment: I haven't test this yet i was unfamiliar with window functions...now that I'm reading about them it's blowing my mind.  Great stuff and thank you so much for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(code) *
FROM price 
INNER JOIN parts ON price.code = part.code 
WHERE price.type='01' 
ORDER BY code, "date" DESC
```

Comment: That worked great!  I tried just DISTINCT earlier but then had group by issues.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct on (code)
    code, p.type, p.date, p.price, p.file
from
    price p
    inner join 
    parts using (code) 
where p.type='01' 
order by code, p.date desc
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT